# Win32 and x64 Platform naming

Tags: c#, api, platform

I have an application that offers an API users can call to get the application platform description. 
Here is my enum:

```
/// <summary>
/// Target platforms
/// </summary>
public enum Platform
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 32-bit platform
    /// </summary>
    Win32,
    /// <summary>
    /// 64-bit platform
    /// </summary>
    X64
}
```

Someone suggested to rename `X64` enum value to Win64. In one hand, it makes sense to rename it to `Win64` to be symmetric with `Win32` value. On the other hand, the platform name `x64` is widely used in Visual Studio and other applications to describe a Windows 64 platform.

Is my enum right? Or should it have `Win64` instead of `x64`?

Comment: I'd choose `Win64` personally, because occasionally *any* 64-bit OS is labeled `X64`, even if it's non-Windows. By naming it `Win64`, it is clear that the platform is *both* Windows and 64-bit.

Comment: Which Win64 platform did you mean?  There's more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides PC grade x64 (AMD64, x86-64) (each costs tens to hundreds of USD), 
there is also Intel IA64 (Itanium) architecture for high-end servers (each costs thousands of USD).

Normally, most of our software only runs on x86 and x86-64 but not Itanium.

There is also Itanium version of Windows.

Therefore, x64 is a better name.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood your answer :p isn't Win64 better in this case? Win64 tells my users the software runs on 64 bits architectures regardless of the processor type;

Comment: It depends whether your program can also run on Itanium. Otherwise, we always talk about x64

Answer (score 2):

I would say what you have chosen is correct. As you say X64 is widely used, I have never seen anyone refer to 64-bit as Win64. If its a requirement to have them symmetrical I would change the Win32 to X86.

Although if your API can be used on multiple operating systems then Win64 may be better, assuming that its only intended to be used for Windows and there's an equivalent for the other OS.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think anyone can give a right answer on this, as whta is right and was it wrong for these kind of things, has to be decided among dev group. If you and others think that `Win64`, is more clear, also because there is also `Win32`, keep it.

Just choose what is appropriate to you.

Enum *naming* is not something that follows rigid guidelines set by someone.

I would, personally, choose `Win64`, in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That is the problem when developing APIs, decisions among dev groups does not help a lot as one has to think about the API's usability and sustainability. As to the guidelines, the Framework Design Book is a good reference that sets some rigid guidelines on exposing enums through API.

Comment: @GETah: In my opinion the name Win32 and Win64 is much clear the x86 and x64.

Answer (score 1):

Personally? I'm not sure if there's a hard solution to this... but looking at most software packages and internet sites it's more common to see "x86" and "x64" than Win32 and Win64. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

This decision is pure convention that you have to define and to document properly in your API

Answer (score -1):

```
Platform GetApplicationPlatform()
{
    switch (IntPtr.Size)
    {
        case 4:
            return Platform.X86;
        case 8:
            return Platform.X64;
        default:
            return Platform.Unknown;
    }
}
```